# macbook Random reboot and forgot the time

Tags: macbook-pro

Macbook just randomly switched itself off, and when I switched it back on again it had forgotten the time (as in, it had set itself to 0000 1st Jan 2001)

[image]

...and had a moan about some applications with alerts of this format...

[image]

When I opened the time/date presferences... the automatic 'get time from central server' kicked in. But I wanted to know if these two symptoms pointed to a specific problem that someone can recognise...

MacBook has these specs...

[image]

Edit next day macBook wouldn't charge. Visited Apple Store, power supply was prononced DOA  (turns out it wasn't an offical power supply it was a cheap knock off).  Problem hasn't reoccured since - will come back in a week and let you know if that has fixed it (which would be odd, but on the other hand the power supply starting to flake out *could* have a bunch of downstream issues - it has been plugged in every time there has been a problem)

Comment: Has it done this more then once?

Comment: It rebooted earlier today, but I didn't notice a change in the time... (and it came up as a warning dialog so I'd like to think it would...) It may well be an isolated incidence, but even so, I'd be interested in the reasons why it might be so...

Comment: Ha - just after I finnished typing - it did exactly the same thing again... *growl* will add some more screenshots.

Comment: You have some serious bug issues. You system is corrupt, need to do the CMD-R to reset it.

Comment: Was the MacBook running on battery or mains when you had this problem?

Comment: @ashley mains.  When restarted it was showing 100% battery.

Comment: Strange! I agree with @MikeyWard's answer, but I am inclined to think of this as two separate issues: 1) the machine switched itself off; 2) the time was reset. I have resolved issue (2) many times on pre-MacBook Mac portables by replacing the internal watch-like battery which powers the internal clock. On a MacBook, though, I believe the internal clock is powered by the main battery. If it was plugged into the mains, though, this doesn't seem terribly relevant, but I thought I'd mention it in case it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahem - it turns out that a faulty (non-apple) charger was to blame - it failed, but before failing properly I understand it wasn't feeding the mac the power it wanted in the way it wanted and may have tripped something...

Answer (score 1):

Time to swing the voodoo chicken.

Things to try, in increasing order of intrusiveness:

1) PRAM reset: Reboot machine, holding Command+Option+P+R. Machine will begin to boot, and then automatically reboot itself. Let this cycle continue for 2-3 reboots, then let go and let the machine boot normally. Yeah, I know.

2) SMC reset (the more likely one): http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

It's entirely possible that the SMC itself is malfunctioning, which would require a logic board replacement. From your description, I think it's unlikely that this is a software-related issue.